# GcmReceiver class not found in Quick Start Sample in GCM DOCS

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

I'm trying to develop an app with GCM,

so I downloaded Sample project made by Google here
: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

At the manifest of this project, there is code for GcmReceiver below:

```
        <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->
```

But At java package, there is no class named GcmReceiver below is the picture the sample project I have show me:
[image]

Just with the manifest xml file, is that GcmReceiver working well?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add at least Play Services 7.5.0 to your project.
I suggest you to add latest library vs 8.3.0

Here's link for gradle users:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"
```

Comment: I already add that code ' compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"

Comment: You mean that If add that code, developer doesn't have to add GcmReceiver.class at java package? what is the connection two things?

Comment: if you import library successfully to your project, you can use GcmReceiver.class you defined in your manifest.

Comment: What do you mean? You mean that I have to create GcmReceiver.class extending BroadcastReceiver? But the sample project from google doesn't that's the core thing I ask

Comment: I mean just import library and add the code below you send to your manifest. if you imported library successfully you can use "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"